# Apache Spark Shared Counter

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm fairly new to Apache Spark and I'm using the GraphX. So I have to use Scala, to which I'm also new ;-).

**UPDATED**

I have a graph, let's say like in the following picture:

[image: Example graph]

Every Node has its own HashMap or List where it can store IDs. Now I'm iterating over the triplets of the graph and if the edge attribute is matching a criteria (which is ignored in this example) then I want to store the same ID in the start and end node of this edge.

After one round of this algorithm the result could look like this:

[image: After one round]

And here the code (shortened):

```
val newNodes = graph.triplets.flatMap(triplet => {
    val newId = Counter.getId();
    val map = List((srcId, newId), (dstId, newId))
    // Outputs sth. like
    //  (1, 1)   (3, 1)   (2, 2)    (3, 2)
}
```

I get the unique ID from the counter object:

```
object Counter{
    private var resultCount: Integer = 0;

    def getResultID(): Integer = {
        resultCount = resultCount + 1;
        return resultCount;
    }
}
```

After the flatMap I'm grouping all tuples by the node id and then put all id for one node in a list (with a map-operator). So the outcome is for node 3: (3, List(1, 2)). This result is then stored back to the graph with an outerJoin.

So my question is, do I have to care about, that the IDs are unique by synchronizing the method or is it okay in this way? If somebody has another idea by solving the whole problem without giving explicitly IDs for example with the zip-Method, then this would also be nice :-).

Beside this question, can someone explain me, what is happening during runtime to the Counter object? Because it's a singleton, does it reside somewhere where the driver is executed (on the Master?), because I read somewhere, that variables which you can use in normal code and then are used while doing parallel computations with Spark, are copied to the Worker/Thread, which shouldn't happen here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are counting things in you're RDDs you should be using [accumulators](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want count things in an RDD. Instead I want to give things an unique ID while I'm doing something with an RDD (which happens distributed). So I don't know if I have to ensure that the IDs are unique and that 2 or more threads could (possibly) get the same one (lost update problem and so on).

Comment: Ah this has an easy solution, gimme a minute to post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to implement this your self, assigning unique ids is so common that spark has it built in already in `def zipWithUniqueId(): RDD[(T, Long)]` as you can see it assigns a unique long to each value, meaning it returns an RDD of tuples. Example usage:

```
val uniqIds = vertexData.zipWithUniqueId().map((k,v)=>(v,k)) //I'm assuming you want the unique ids as the vertexId
```

You could also do this with the edge attributed

Comment: Thanks. After thinking about a solution with zip it worked for me.

Comment: @th0rsch glad my answer helped sorry for kinda ignoring your other comment