# create unique values for each key in a spark RDD

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to create an RDD of `key, value` pairs where each key would have a unique value. The purpose is to "remember" key indices for later use since keys might be shuffled around the partitions, and basically create a lookup table of sorts. I am vectorizing some text and need to create feature vectors so I have to have a unique value for each key.

I tried this with zipping a second RDD to my RDD of keys, but the problem is that if the two RDDs are not partitioned in exactly the same way, you end up losing elements.

My second attempt is to use a hash generator like [the one used in scikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/murmurhash.pyx) but I'm wondering if there is some other "spark-native" way of doing this? I'm using PySpark, not Scala...

Comment: probably something like this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179047/apache-spark-shared-counter/25186647#25186647)

Comment: thanks @aaronman -- but that doesn't seem to be an option for pyspark?

Comment: Oh that's annoying in that case I recommend looking at the [source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1040) and seeing if you can implement the equivalent in python, it doesn't seem to bad

Comment: thanks for the tip, I'll post my solution as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zipWithIndex` and `zipWithUniqueId` were just added to PySpark (https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/2092) and will be available in the forthcoming Spark 1.1.0 release (they're currently available in the Spark `master` branch).

If you're using an older version of Spark, you should be able cherry-pick that commit in order to backport these functions, since I think it only adds lines to `rdd.py`.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @aaronman this is a [simple operation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1040) that for some reason hasn't made it into the pyspark api yet. Going off the Java implementation, here's what seems to work (but gives indices with consecutive ordering on each partition):

```
def count_partitions(id, iterator): 
    c = sum(1 for _ in iterator)
    yield (id,c) 

def zipindex(l, indices, k) :
    start_index = indices[k]
    for i,item in enumerate(l) :
        yield (item,start_ind+i)

> parts = rdd.mapPartitionsWithSplit(count_partitions).collectAsMap()

> indices = parts.values()

> indices.append(0,0)

> rdd_index = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(lambda k,l: zipindex(l,indices,k))
```

Comment: I wanted to create unique keys for each item rather than unique values and this code was very useful.