# Assigning indexes to keys in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This is my first post here and I hope I followed the guidelines properly.

I'm currently working with an RDD of `spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating` (key1, key2, value) and I'd like to apply Spark's MLLib SVD to it as [in this example](https://gist.github.com/vrilleup/9e0613175fab101ac7cd). To do so, I need to create a (sparse) `RowMatrix`. I'm able to do it by applying

```
val inputData = data.map{ case Rating(key1, key2, ecpm) =>  (key1, key2, ecpm)}

// Number of columns
val nCol = inputData.map(_._2).distinct().count().toInt

// Construct rows of the RowMatrix
val dataRows = inputData.groupBy(_._1).map[(Long, Vector)]{ row =>
  val (indices, values) = row._2.map(e => (e._2, e._3)).unzip
  (row._1, new SparseVector(nCol, indices.toArray, values.toArray))
}

// Compute 20 largest singular values and corresponding singular vectors
val svd = new RowMatrix(dataRows.map(_._2).persist()).computeSVD(20, computeU = true)
```

My problem is, when I try to run this code, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 72 in stage 12.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 72.3 in stage 12.0 (TID 2329, spark7): Java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1085194
```

I guess this `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error comes from the fact that my `key1` and `key2` keys are integers that can possibly be big (that is, too big for a `RowMatrix` object indices). So what I have tried to do is to assign new indices to `key1` and `key2` which respectively lie in [1, n_key1] and [1, n_key2]. I have seen a few related topics (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828815/how-to-get-element-by-index-in-spark-rdd-java) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384604/create-unique-values-for-each-key-in-a-spark-rdd)) using methods like `zipWithIndex` or `zipWithUniqueId` but I don't think it really helps in my case. I was thinking of applying something like

```
inputData.map{(key1, key2, value) => key1}.distinct().zipWithIndex()
```

and the same for `key2`. This would give me indices for both keys but then I don't know how I can recover an RDD of the same shape as `inputData`. I'm quite new to Scala/Spark and I can't think of a way to do it. Any though on how I could solve my problem, that is, how to replace the `key1` and `key2` keys by some indices in my RDD? Note that `key1` and `key2` are not unique for all samples, there may be repetitions.

EDIT: My data looks like this:

```
scala> data.take(5)
res3: Array[org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating] = Array(Rating(39150941,1020026,0.0), Rating(33640847,1029671,0.0), Rating(7447392,988161,0.0), Rating(41696301,1130435,0.0), Rating(42941712,461150,0.0))
```

Comment: Great question! Is there any way you could include some sample data (just a row or two) so we can run your code? Something along these lines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for your answer evan058. I have included the 5 first rows of my RDD at the end of my initial post.